# tab based problems in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i am iPhone programmer and new in android development ,
I developed a tab host based application.
Can I switch between activites as I was doing in iphone 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:
and 
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:
is there any way of doing this like of thing in android?
Please help

Comment: Alloush how are you setting your Activity?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: ok good so you can switch between activities... when you click on tabs

Comment: ok see we have three tab tabA,Tabb,TabC, and we hav four activities ,A,B,C,D.ON TabC i want to switch to Activity D but tabbar should remain on its position

Comment: You need to use ActivityGroup but It is depreciated now so you need to use fragments. search on the internet. I have code for ActivityGroup if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two xml layouts and write ur necessary codings there.Now create a new activity and for tabhost and add the tabs u need and u need to include the two xml layouts in tab host

```
public class UserCreation extends TabActivity {

    protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_creation);
    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabhost=getTabHost();
        Intent createUserIntent=new Intent().setClass(this, UserCreationFragment.class);
        TabSpec tabspecUserCreation= tabhost.newTabSpec("Create user")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.insert_user)).setContent(createUserIntent);
        Intent deleteUserIntent=new Intent().setClass(this, Deleteuser.class);
        TabSpec tabspecuserDeletion=tabhost.newTabSpec("Delete user").setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.del_user))
                .setContent(deleteUserIntent);
        tabhost.addTab(tabspecUserCreation);
        tabhost.addTab(tabspecuserDeletion);
    }


}
```

refer the following example for better reference

[Android Tabhost](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)